# Get page source from a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-get

I need to fetch source code from a given url. I've tried using :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://google.com', false);
xhr.send(null);
var data=xhr.responseText;
```

But this does not work for me. So, I tried using ajax given in one of the SO link but it didn't work for me :

```
$.get( "http://google.com", function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
        alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try using `https` over `http`?

Comment: If you paste the error into google I bet you will get some useful information on why it isn't working. You're running into the [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: It will not work, because you are hitting cross domain and cross domain is restricted

Comment: @TinyGiant I've searched for it already and I've tried using CORS extension on google chrome and `xhr.withCredentials = true;` also.

Comment: @RitikSaxena yes I've tried it

Comment: @muneebShabbir but it should work with  CORS extension toggled off, right?

Comment: @Ishan But using extension is not a solution. Then your application will work only on chrome with specific extension enable, which is not good

Comment: @muneebShabbir yes, you are right. Is there any way to get the source of a url ? I need to send this source to some other link. They are separate applications running on localhost but with different ports.

Comment: Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the resource you're trying to request.